# What python html generator module should I use in a non-web application?

Tags: python, html-generation

I'm hacking a quick and dirty python script to generate some reports as static html files.

What would be a good module to easily build static html files outside the context of a web application?

My goals are simplicity (the HTML will not be very complex) and ease of use (I don't want to write a lot of code just to output some html tags).

I found two alternatives on my first goolge search:

- markup.py - http://markup.sourceforge.net/
- HTML.py - http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html

Also, I feel that using a templating engine would be over-kill, but if you differ please say it and why.

Any other recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could try [Markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) instead, and convert it to HTML on the fly?

Comment: Hmmm... Nice idea. Will consider it for sure.

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need something complex - for instance, here's a ~150 line library to generate HTML in a functional manner:

http://github.com/Yelp/PushmasterApp/blob/master/pushmaster/taglib.py

(Full disclosure, I work with the person who originally wrote that version, and I also use it myself.)

Comment: Thanks!, I will check it out. Specially, thanks for recommending something that you have used.

Answer (score 3):

Why would a templating engine necessarily be overkill? You don't need the whole web framework just to use the templating engine (at least, for most templating engines). [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) for example can be used stand-alone just fine, and I often use it to generate html files (reports from a db and such)

Answer (score 2):

If you have just some simple static HTML files. Then why not use string templates like so.

```
import string

TEMPLATE_FORMAT = """
<html>
<head><title>Trial</title></head>
<body>
    <div class="myclass">$my_div_data</div>
</body>
"""
my_div_data = "some_data_to_display_in_HTML"
TEMPLATE    = string.Template(TEMPLATE_FORMAT)
html_data   = TEMPLATE.safe_substitute(my_div_data)
open("out.html", "w").write(html_data)
```

Give this a shot if you don't have too big HTML files to generate. Saves you on the learning you need to do if you decide to use libraries.

Answer (score 2):

ElementTree can produce html with some limitations. I'd write it like this:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement
import sys 

html = Element('html')

head = SubElement(html, 'head')
style = SubElement(head, 'link')
style.attrib = {'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': 'style.css', 'type': 'text/css'}
body = SubElement(html, 'body')

para = SubElement(body, 'p')
para.text = 'Lorem ipsum sit amet'

doc = ElementTree(html)
doc.write(sys.stdout)
```

In case of moderately complex html I'd stick with some templating engine: Jinja2, Mako, Cheetah, just to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend having a look at [shpaml](http://shpaml.webfactional.com/)